# Problems with Masonry, jQuery and imagesLoaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, jquery-masonry

Web noobie here. I'm having a problem getting Masonry to work properly with the site I'm building. Here is the code I'm trying to execute:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
...
var $article_display = $('#article_display');
        $article_display.imagesLoaded(function() {
          $article_display.masonry({
            columnWidth: Math.floor($('#article_display').width() *.3) + 2,
            itemSelector: '.article',
            isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions
          });
        });
...
});
```

I'm getting this error: "**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imagesLoaded' .**" I've looked around for the past two days to find some kind of solution to this before posting this question here and have been  unsuccessful so far. It seems like my browser isn't recognizing that I've included the imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js file...? According to the reference material here: http://masonry.desandro.com/appendix.html this code should work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can try to get a jsfiddle set up if that would make a difference.

Thanks!

Edit: Here's a JSFiddle showing the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/DDQtD/

Comment: are you sure "http://masonry.desandro.com/masonry.pkgd.min.js" is loaded properly

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the script before this is being executed?

Comment: I believe both scripts are loading before the code executes. I load the scripts at the top of my HTML (I know it's bad practice) just to be sure. The console isn't showing me anything else that leads me to believe they aren't loading and the code I'm  trying to execute is wrapped in the $(document).ready(...) function.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this site works... I'll post here again to see if it'll bring my topic back up so I can get some feedback  with that JSFiddle :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had a typo when I was loading my scripts, it looked like this:

```
<script type="filepath/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

I needed to switch out **type** with **src**. So many simple mistakes!

Answer (score 0):

I would try Salvattore, it works in a different way so images don't have to load before the script is loaded, and you can configure the script with CSS and HTML.

http://salvattore.com/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll check out Salvattore later today. Turns out it was a simple typo on my part that I wasn't seeing that was causing the problems.